# Swift default parameter & Selector Syntax

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, selector

I have a function that takes a default parameter:

```
func myFunc(foo: Bool = true) { }
```

I'm trying to figure out the correct `Selector` syntax for it as I'm adding it as a target for a `UIRefreshControl`

```
 self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("myFunc"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

I have tried both `Selector("myFunc")` and `Selector("myFunc:")` - both crash with invalid selector error.

Had a scour of the web but no solutions were thrown up. Can someone assist? Thanks

Comment: Does that even compile?

Comment: when `bar` is a string yes. Updated it now to make it clearer

Comment: Please paste in the code you're using to add a target

Comment: @Shai done. It worked fine before I added the default parameter to `myFunc` so I know it's the Selector syntax that's the problem

Comment: Where is `myFunc` defined?

Comment: Within the same class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a crash because it expects a different parameter. 'addTarget' expects to get a function who's sole parameter (if any) is AnyObject (or maybe UIView), not Bool

Comment: That causes a crash (unrecognized selector)

Comment: The argument should be a `UIRefreshControl` (in this case, since he's trying to add the target to a `UIRefreshControl`), but anything up the inheritance tree would work: `UIControl`, `UIView`, `UIResponder`, `NSObject`, or `id` (`AnyObject` in Swift).

Answer (score 5):

We are trying to add an action to a UI element.  Consider the options that Xcode presents us with if we try to hook up a control from our interface builder file to our view controller class:

[image]

Much like the method you're using, Interface Builder is asking us for multiple things.

- Interface builder knows which control is the sender (where we initiated the Ctrl+drag from... this equates to your `self.refreshControl` which is what we're calling `addTarget` on).
- Interface builder knows what class is the target (we Ctrl+dragged to it).
- Interface builder asks for the name of a method we're about to create.  In your case, you chose that when you wrote the method.
- Interface builder asks us how the sender should be passed.  It gives us, in the case of a button, the option of `AnyObject` (default) or `UIButton`.  In the case of a `UIRefreshControl`, the options would be `AnyObject` or `UIRefreshControl`.  This is passed as the "sender" object.
- Interface builder asks us for which events should this method be called (just as the `addTarget` method does).

And finally, Interface builder asks us what sorts of arguments should be passed:

[image]

We have three options here.

We can pass no arguments, in which case, we'd have a method that looks like this:

```
func myFunc() {

}
```

Or we can pass the "sender", in which case the method would look like this:

```
func myFunc(sender: AnyObject) {

}
```

But the type of `sender` will vary depending on what we actually try to send.

Or we could pass the sender and the event type (useful if multiple events are tied to the same method):

```
func myFunc(sender: AnyObject, forEvent event: UIEvent) {

}
```

If done through Interface builder, we'll also have an `@IBAction` stuck out at the beginning, but that's not what we're doing in your example.

Now, if this were Objective-C, our method would look something like this:

```
- (void)myFunc:(id)sender {

}
```

And Objective-C does not support overloading, so it would not allow another function in the same class that looks like this:

```
- (void)myFunc:(BOOL)foo {

}
```

You can't have two methods with the same name.

Swift, however, does support method overloading, and as such, the same class *could* have both of the following methods:

```
func myFunc(foo: AnyObject) {

}

func myFunc(foo: Bool) {

}
```

These are entirely different methods in the eyes of Swift, and perfectly fine.

Your code, however, only has the latter.  A method called `myFunc` which takes a Bool argument.

When you try to add the `addTarget:` method, Swift is looking for a method with the name you gave it (`myFunc:`) which can accept a `UIRefreshControl` argument.  It can't find an overload.

Effectively, the error you are getting is sort of the same as this error:

[image]

The point is, Swift can't find a method called `myFunc:` that can accept a `UIRefreshControl` argument.